# SQL Server Analysis Services - bug?

Tags: sql-server, service, analysis

There was a problem with the SQL Server Analysis Services. If I select more than 15 slots in the consolidated table, I get an error:

> The query optimizer has created too many nested cubes in the query plan.

Question: how to fix this? Perhaps this is an undocumented error.

Thank you.

Comment: I've faced with the same issue and found answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/da2391c3-a22e-4a2a-80ee-76b46cc818fd/query-optimizer-generated-too-many-subcubes-in-the-query-plan?forum=sqlanalysisservices